# Registry Edit on Windows 7 isn't persisted for DefaultUserName and DefaultPassword

Tags: c#, windows-7, registry

I have written a C# application to change registry values AutoLogon, DefaultUserName, and DefaultPassword on Windows 7.

The complete path would be "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon"

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\WinLogon", true);
if(key != null)
{      
     key.SetValue("DefaultUserName", "username");
     key.SetValue("DefaultPassword", "password");
}
```

This code executes without any error or exception, But there are no changes affected in registry.

I have executed as Admin and the system on which this gets executed has one user and it is admin.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `key.Close()` as it would never be saved otherwise.

Like this:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\WinLogon", true);

if(key != null)
{
    key.SetValue("DefaultUserName", "username");
    key.SetValue("DefaultPassword", "password");
    key.Close();
}
```

Here's a link from MS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/h5e7chcf.aspx